# iOS app does not respond to some clicks when downloaded from AppStore but works fine in Debug mode

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, app-store

I've made an app (called BeSharp), tested it a lot, uploaded it to Apple AppStore, and now all users report that the pop-up menu I use (custom one) does not respond to clicks.

It does not crash, so I don't understand how to get some debugging done.

So, the question:
How can I debug release version?

Thanks in advance.

P.S. Please find below some promo-codes if you wish to test an app yourself:
FAYNW9XTTMPY
LYK7EYJYJM4E
T6FW34E4TL6J
NJ99R4E39WEW
PJ473MERJKTH
MK4EMXE9XFFW
LN7AFXHJN9YK
MTTKW4PMXPFP
KK9HE74MKFJL
X6PWPHERHMLF
E7P96NNNAAN6
N93FFTPPA366
T9JX6PMN9ELT
JP39XKTT4J6N
Y3Y4R643E6F3
33HWLF4PFJPA
7XYW7NAH7A63
JNP4EYJHKLN6
46KPNPYFYALJ

Comment: You cannot debug a release version, at least not without jailbreaking the device first. Have you tested on all iOS versions and all three available screen sizes?

Comment: Not clear: Does the store version fail on your own phone? There are significant version-to-version differences in the way that popup menus respond.

Comment: Have you downloaded the app from the store on your own device? Do you see the same behavior? If not, the problem might be a specific resolution or OS (or combination of both)

Comment: I've used X6PWPHERHMLF code. Your menu don't working on my iPhone 4 (iOS 6.1.3) and device logs shows nothing.

Comment: Are you sure that for the first time the app is launched you are not performing some heavy computing on the UI thread and cahce it so that for the future launches it will not do the same computing. This happens a lot on the simulator/debug mode while you test the app, you simply don't remove it form the simulator/test device

Comment: How do you click on an iPhone app?  I think you mean tap.

Comment: @mvds No, i've tried only iPhone 5 and probably need to check also iPhone 4. Thanks for a tip. But when I test on real iPhone5 using debug version - it works, but when I am using the same phone and downloading app from AppStore - it doesn't.

Comment: @HotLicks Version is the same (except for debug/release difference).

Comment: @lostInTransit Yes, for me the bug is the same when I download from appstore.

Comment: @danypata The app is very simple, it doesn't contain any computations at all. And all other GUI things work just fine apart from this menu.

Comment: @dacopenhagen I mean tap :)

Comment: Are you sure the app you sent to the store is the same one you tested??

Comment: I see the problem, the popup appears but doesn't function. Here's a random hypothesis: your testing/simulator build folder still contains old (e.g. non-localized) xib files, that overrule xib files added later. The Distribution build effectively starts out clean, so effectively uses other xib files than you are seeing. Can you try and see if your development build shows the same behavior once you clean, "clean build folder", restart xcode, remove app from device, and rebuild?

Comment: used JP39XKTT4J6N . Will let you know if I can figure what the issue is

Comment: are you doing anything like #if DEBUG or RELEASE #endif ?

Comment: @HotLicks Yes, I haven't changed a bit after submitting to appstore

Comment: @calvinBhai No, I don't use it.

Comment: @mvds I have only one XIB file (i don't localize it), so I will try to Clean but don't think it will help. BTW, iPhone4 debug works.

Comment: UPDATE: Everything looks like buttons are not being pressed, and only big black background button is pressed, which causes popup to dissappear. So, as hypothesis, i have these: 1. Buttons on this popup menu uses transparent PNG files as masks. So is it possible that PNG files for release version are different? 2. Maybe layout changes somehow (this background button becomes foreground for example)? I get some errors that constrains are disabled, I think it occurs in another part of an interface, but who knows...

Comment: I'm guessing that when you rebuilt for shipment to the store something changed.

Comment: @HotLicks ok, will try to rebuild it again and submit once again if nothing will be understandable

Comment: Be sure to test it on as many different configurations as possible first.

Comment: @HotLicks Hm, after more thoughts I don't think it's the case. As i've said, I've tried to run the app on the same device in debug version - it works fine. So no changes were made.

Comment: Have you tested it after building in release mode?

Comment: @HotLicks how can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everybody for comments.

I solved the issue.

After inserting some NSLog into code, and running release version on real device, I have pinpointed the issue, and it was in custom button component - in 6.1 some Alpha test function works incorrectly.

So I just updated it and everything worked fine.